# What is the difference to the compiler between these Scripts.Render statements?

Tags: asp.net, razor

This does *not* work:

```
@if (foo) {
   Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bar");
   Styles.Render("~/Content/bar");
}
```

This does work:

```
@if (foo) {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bar")
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/bar")
}
```

Why?  Because of the if statement, I should be inside a code block and these chunks of code should be the same. The top example compiles and runs and does not throw an error.  It just doesn't render any scripts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ sign just tells Razor to write the resulting `string` or `MvcString` to the page. If it it omitted, like your example above, the function is still executed, but it just doesn't get written to the page.
You get the same behavior with other functions like `RenderSection` - they have to have the @ prefix to include the result on the page.

Comment: Thank you! I had thought the @ sign was just used to tell Razor that you were switching to code rather than typing out text that would be on the resulting page. That makes sense.